# "see yourself" vs. "see for yourself"

Tags: difference

I am aware that the phrase "see for yourself" is the correct way to say you see something with your own eyes,  But what "for" is there? For example:

> John did all the work you had given him, see for yourself.

But would it be correct to say the phrase without the preposition "for" like "...see yourself"?

Comment: If *for* was removed, it might come off as the speaker requesting that the listener take a look at themselves, instead of looking at sth. else; *"..see yourself"*. Also, this phrase is the second half of, *"Don't take my word for it, see for yourself."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By itself, the phrase "see for yourself" means to look at something with one's own eyes.

By itself, the phrase "see yourself" is a phrase in the imperative mood; that is, it is a command telling someone to look at themselves.

In the example that you gave, you *could* say "see yourself" and the person will know that you are *non* telling them to look at themselves, rather you are telling them to look at what was specified.

**However**, they will only know that because of **context**, and *not* because "see yourself" can have the same meaning as "see for yourself". It doesn't. Just like how I can understand someone even if they break some grammer rules, so to can a person understand what is actually being said in that sentence despite its incorrectness.

Long story short, it is not correct to drop the 'for'.